# How to count every row from select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to extract the data from my table and I want to have this result:

```
1 Valore
2 Valore
3 Valore
4 Valore
```

So I want to numeration every ROW from 1 to N.

This is my query but not works:

```
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.F_ElementStringFromCodeDescription(RR.ID, RR.DisplayName)) AS Count, 
         dbo.F_ElementStringFromCodeDescription(RR.ID, RR.DisplayName) AS NAME
    FROM AA_V_PHR_CCD_ResultsObservation R INNER JOIN 
         AA_V_PHR_CCD_ResultsObservationXLanguages RR   ON R.ID = RR.ID
   WHERE CodeSystem = '123456789'
GROUP BY dbo.F_ElementStringFromCodeDescription(RR.ID, RR.DisplayName)
```

> EDIT

My Database is Tsql

and this is my extract data:

```
1 Valore
1 Pippo
1 Pluto
```

Instead of

```
1 Valore
2 Pippo
3 Pluto
```

Comment: Which sql database and please post your data

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Not sure about the database you are using. Maybe see if it supports something like `Rownum` ?

Comment: @Elyasin purely informational - OP mentions DB is TSQL, so the database is SQL Server, and yes, SQL Server has a `ROW_NUMBER()` function that does what you would expect (with the usual levels of flexibility etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The count does not change per-row; there are the same number of rows every time; what you seem to want is not a count, but a row-number.

To get a row-number, you need to use [the `ROW_NUMBER` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql); for example:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
   ORDER BY dbo.F_ElementStringFromCodeDescription(RR.ID, RR.DisplayName)) as [Position],
dbo.F_ElementStringFromCodeDescription(RR.ID, RR.DisplayName) as [Name]
...
ORDER BY dbo.F_ElementStringFromCodeDescription(RR.ID, RR.DisplayName)
```

However, unless you are *actually* partitioning (so getting a row-number per partition), it would be easier to handle this at the receiving client.

Answer (score 1):

You could do using the rownum function. This would be specific to each DB you are using, but here's an example from oracle:

```
Select rownum, <ColumnList> from 
       (select <ColumnList> ...)
```

The [TSQL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) says that the equivalent is ROW_NUMBER() function.

For TSQL:

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER
   ([PartitionBy] OrderByClause), <ColumnList>...
```

Comment: the syntax for `OVER` is *not* `(Select ColumnList ...)`

Comment: @MarcGravell Apologies. Corrected the same.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Count, 
     dbo.F_ElementStringFromCodeDescription(RR.ID, RR.DisplayName) AS NAME
FROM AA_V_PHR_CCD_ResultsObservation R INNER JOIN 
     AA_V_PHR_CCD_ResultsObservationXLanguages RR   ON R.ID = RR.ID
WHERE CodeSystem = '123456789'
GROUP BY dbo.F_ElementStringFromCodeDescription(RR.ID, RR.DisplayName)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution is the fastest

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  VAL VARCHAR(64));

INSERT INTO Test (ID,VAL) VALUES (8,"a"),(156,"b"),(99,"c");

SET @t1=0;
SELECT @t1:=@t1 + 1 as 'num', VAL FROM Test;
```

OUT

```
num | VAL
1   | a
2   | c
3   | b
```

Comment: The question is tagged tsql, so: SQL Server, which means... that doesn't apply; and although you can do the "mutate a variable per row" thing in SQL Server, that *particular* scenario will raise error 141 "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.". But I strongly suggest that *on all platforms*, you'd be much better using the inbuilt "rownum" or "row_number" (or whatever) API - the engine is optimized for that. I utterly dismiss your "is the fastest" comment, especially without context and data. I'd settle for "it works OK".

Comment: You're wrong if you put them ":" it works, show this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/245f6c/6

Comment: Now look up at the top of that fiddle where it says "MySQL 5.6". TSQL is *specifically* the variant of SQL used by SQL Server (MySQL's variant is called, perhaps unoriginally, MySQL) . Change that drop-down to be SQL Server (any version) and retry.